# react native navigation error "navigate is undefined"

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am creating a react native application and I have problem when I want to navigate between screens it gives error as " Cannot read property 'navigate' of Undefined " . I want when I press gear icon it must navigate to settings part . I couldn't clearly see where did I mistake .

settings button touchable opacity

```js
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import PS from '../screens/PS';
import SPC from '../screens/SPC';
import TFA from '../screens/2FA';
import Login from '../screens/Login';
import Settings from '../screens/settings';

const screens = {
    Login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
          }
    },
    TFA:{

        screen: TFA
    },
    PS: {
        screen: PS,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
          }
    },
    SPC: {
        screen: SPC
    },
    Settings: {
        screen: Settings
    }
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);


import React, {useState}from 'react';
import SettingsButton from './SettingsButton';
import ConnectionIcon from './Connectionİcon';
import { View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const Header = () => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <View style={styles.headerp1}></View>
                <View style={styles.headerp2}><Image 
                    source={require('../assets/images/monitor.png')}
                /></View>
            <View style={styles.headerp3}>
                <SettingsButton />
                <ConnectionIcon />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Header;

// const styles here
```

```html
import React from 'react';
import { Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


const SettingsButton = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.headerp3v2}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
        >
            <Image style={styles.reddot}
                source={require('../assets/images/gear.png')}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

export default SettingsButton;


   // const stlyes codes here
```

header file is here

````
import { Image, StyleSheet, Button, View, Text, SafeAreaView, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import PV from '../components/PV';
export default function PS() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar hidden />
            <Header />
            <View><Text style={styles.text}>All Persons</Text></View>
            <PV />
            <Footer/>
        </View>
    );
}```
````

Comment: Where are you using the Header component ? also you are not passing a navigation prop to the SettingsButton from the header

Comment: I added header component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass `navigation` prop into `SettingsButton`

You can try use `useNavigation` hook https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/ for get navigation object into `SettingsButton`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'; // <-- new code


const SettingsButton = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation(); // <-- new code

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.headerp3v2}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
        >
            <Image style={styles.reddot}
                source={require('../assets/images/gear.png')}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

export default SettingsButton;
```

Comment: I did it as you told but it still gives same error.

Comment: @nogabemist try remove `ConnectionIcon` component in `Header`, maybe in there you also use navigation without props